# How to get Amazon S3 objects in a loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, fs

In Node.js I'm attempting to retrieve objects by looping through an array using the `fs.createReadStream` and `fs.createWriteStream` methods.

AWS documentation shows how to retrieve a single object with
`s3.getObject(params).createReadStream().pipe(file);`

But with params and Amazon S3 set as

```
  const params = { Bucket:'user_events' };
  const s3 = new AWS.S3();
```

When I call my function:

```
  function gets3Objects(eventsArray) {
    console.log('--> finding files from s3...');
    const arrLen = eventsArray.length;
    let iter = 0;

    s3.listObjects(params, (err, data) => {
      for (let i = 0; i < arrLen; i += 1) {
        let  file = eventsArray[i];
        params.Key = file;
        let fileOut = fs.createWriteStream(`./tmp/${file}`);
        let stream = s3.getObject(params).createReadStream().pipe(fileOut);
        console.log(i, arrLen, eventsArray[i]);

        stream.on('close', () => {
          iter += 1;
          console.log(`${i} -- file added: ${eventsArray[i]}`);

          if (iter === arrLen) {
            console.log('-- success! --');
            delete params.Key;
            return;
          }
        });
    });
  }
```

The output produces:

```
--> finding files from s3...
0 9 'harry_test_audio_09.wav'
1 9 'harry_test_audio_08.wav'
2 9 'harry_test_audio_07.wav'
3 9 'harry_test_audio_06.wav'
4 9 'harry_test_audio_05.wav'
5 9 'harry_test_audio_04.wav'
6 9 'harry_test_audio_03.wav'
7 9 'harry_test_audio_02.wav'
8 9 'harry_test_audio_01.wav'
6 -- file added: harry_test_audio_03.wav
8 -- file added: harry_test_audio_01.wav
7 -- file added: harry_test_audio_02.wav
0 -- file added: harry_test_audio_09.wav
5 -- file added: harry_test_audio_04.wav
1 -- file added: harry_test_audio_08.wav
3 -- file added: harry_test_audio_06.wav
4 -- file added: harry_test_audio_05.wav
2 -- file added: harry_test_audio_07.wav
-- success! --
```

Which produces 9 files with correct names each with only the content of the first file inside.

I also tried using `stream.on('finish' ...` and `stream.on('end' ...` with similar results.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you can use "list objects" method present in s3client. I am not sure about the way to write a code in node.js. But in java, there is a method listObjects(ListObjectsRequest) and in ListObjectsRequest you can set bucket name and prefix. With the help of this you can get list of objects present in your s3 bucket. After that you can fetch Object summaries. Each object summary contains one key from that bucket. you can loop object summaries and use getObject on each key derived from that loop.

Comment: Most likely when something like this happens in Javascript it has to do something with closures. I didn't debug your code, but it sounds like this is the problem. Read more about this on for example: https://decembersoft.com/posts/understanding-javascript-closures-in-for-loops/

Comment: Thanks @Suyash, but `listObjects();` only returns the names and metadata of the objects in s3, while I'm trying to write the actual files to tmp/

Comment: u may want to check whether the readstream.pipe blocks or whether its async with independ lifecycle events indicating 'onData' , onEnd...  if its the latter then u would need to alter the code to be async to wait til each stream / each fileOut  finishes inside the loop

Comment: using listObjects() you will get object of ObjectsListings from which you can get list of object summaries. Each object summary contains the metadata which contains the s3 object key. So using that key and bucket name with getObject() you can retrieve actual object from s3 bucket. You want to fetch all the objects from s3 bucket, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered the same problem and it was due to bad closure in the loop.
The solution is to create a copy of params that is not shared among all the iterations.

```
function gets3Objects(eventsArray) {
  console.log('--> finding files from s3...');
  const arrLen = eventsArray.length;
  let iter = 0;

  s3.listObjects(params, (err, data) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < arrLen; i += 1) {
      let  fileParams = {
        Bucket: 'user_events',
        Key: eventsArray[i]
      }
      let fileOut = fs.createWriteStream(`./tmp/${file}`);
      let stream = s3.getObject(fileParams).createReadStream().pipe(fileOut);
      console.log(i, arrLen, eventsArray[i]);

      stream.on('close', () => {
        iter += 1;
        console.log(`${i} -- file added: ${eventsArray[i]}`);

        if (iter === arrLen) {
          console.log('-- success! --');
          return;
        }
      });
    }
  });
}
```